# How to Share Activity Screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Hello Great Android Developers,

I want to create an android app which will contain a whiteboard, Video Chat Option, Document sharing etc. Like shown in the video on bottom of this website https://www.vedantu.com/

I can develop all required contents in app but the problem is to share screen among the users. can you help me on how to share android activity or screen in real time with users?

Comment: I request you to please put your queries if you are stuck in any code else it will attract negative voting in that case.

Comment: 1) looks like you have to have root access for that. 2) check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052113/android-screen-sharing-programmatically-root